# Iso 14443 request command

Tags: c#

I am trying to communicate with some smart card.
I have reader which has method to Request 14443A type card.
When I issue this command *sometimes it returns success, sometimes
it fails*.
Am I missing something in the **14443A protocol maybe**? Maybe the card enters some halt state? Or I must call halt state manually if there is failure? Or there is some other command I must call beforehand?
Where can I get information on how to establish communication (on the protocol level) with ISO14443 card?
Is there some tutorial for this?

This is how code looks like(roughly):

```
 SerialPort p = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
 p.Open();

 byte[] res;
 res = send(p, REQUEST_TYPEA_COMMAND);
 res = send(p, RESETA_COMMAND);
 // send some other command
 p.Close();
```

If I run above code for first time, all calls are OK. But after second run of the program, the first call (REQUEST_TYPEA_COMMAND) fails - until I restart the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A card not responding to REQA commands could have several reasons:

1. It's not an ISO 14443 Type A card. In that case it won't (should not) respond to any REQA commands. As your card sometimes does, this is certainly not the case.
2. The card did not receive the REQA command. This could happen if there where transmission errors on the physical link (air interface).
3. The card is not in IDLE state. A card starts in IDLE state after reset (i.e. field on). If the card receives a REQA command, it transitions to READY state. Receiving any other command than an anti-collision command with matched UID part while in READY state resets the card back into IDLE state where it then can process further REQA commands. If the card is further activated beyond READY state and receives a HLTA command (or DESELECT if activated up to ISO 14443-4 protocol layer), it switches into HALT state. In HALT state a card will not respond to REQA commands but only to WUPA (wakeup commands).